# Getting a Component to copy from another Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm at the beginning of learning C# by practice.

I came a few times to the conclusion that having one big script with all the information and methods is not convenient even for a one-person Project.

So I tried to split the script in many smaller ones and came to the problem of getting a Component (Vector2) from the Script (MausControll) that defines the position I clicked on with the Tag “Ground”.
I made it work that the script should read it out though GetComonent due to another persons' topic in this forum, but the value doesn't show up in the parameter.

```
public GameObject MC;
public Vector2 targetPos;
public Vector2 targetPos2;
public float speed;
public bool isMoving;
public float hightDiff;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    targetPos = new Vector2(gameObject.GetComponent<MausControll>().targetPosG.x, 
                            gameObject.GetComponent<MausControll>().targetPosG.y);
    
    targetPos2 = new Vector2(targetPos.x, targetPos.y + hightDiff);

    //wenn targetPos2 nicht der Ort ist an dem der MC steht, dann muss isMoving true werden
    CheckSpriteFlip();
}
```

And the MausControll Script is this, the important part

```
public Vector3 mausPos;
public Camera mainCamera;
public Vector3 mausPosWorld;
public Vector2 mausPosWorld2D;
RaycastHit2D hit;
public Vector2 targetPosG;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Hovercontroll und Grafiken fehlen
    
    //Linke Mouse wird gedrückt wird, dann
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Linke Maustaste wurde gedrückt");
        mausPos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log("ScreenSpace:" + mausPos);
        mausPosWorld = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mausPos);
        Debug.Log("WorldSpace:" + mausPosWorld);
        mausPosWorld2D = new Vector2(mausPosWorld.x, mausPosWorld.y);
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mausPosWorld2D, Vector2.zero);
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Es wurde ein Collider erkannt");
            
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                targetPosG = hit.point;
            }
            else if...
```

I don't quite understand where the problem is, cause not even an error is showing up.

Comment: You do not want to do `GetComponent` every frame in `Update`! Do it **once** in `Awake` or `Start`, store that reference in a class field and reuse it. Or just have a `[SerializeField] private` or `public MouseControl mouseControl;` and drag component into the field in the Inspector and forget about `GetComponent` alltogether

Comment: Then also in general instead of using `new Vector2` and create it component wise you can just go `targetPos = GetComponent<MausControll>().targetPosG;`

Comment: Since the targetPosG will be given as a position to move to when a left mouseclick is done, the value of targetPosG will change with every leftclick that is done by Raycast. I would like to change the value of targetPos of the MovementControllscript acording to the targetPosG value that gets updated on update if a raycast is casted, do you mind helping me there?